# Getting error message while parsing data to android using JSONparser

Tags: android, android-activity

This is my code to display the jsondata on an android device

```
try
    {
        JSONArray jArray=new JSONArray(result) ;
        for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++)
        {
            JSONObject json= jArray.getJSONObject(i);
            String record=json.getString("name");
            Integer record1=json .getInt("age");
            records.add(record+"\n"+record1+"\n");
        }
    }
```

android studio show the following error

```
error parsing dataorg.json.JSONException: Value {"name":"drishya","age":"24"} of type org.json.JSONObj
```

Comment: what's your question? you should add more code to support your question

Comment: age is a string, not an int. please post an actual question and a full backtrace next time.